# Android Studio checkout master not possible

Tags: git, android-studio, github, version-control, git-checkout

I created a new branch via Android Studio and pushed a version of my app into it. Next I used checkout master to go back to my other branch and kept working.

Everything worked well until then.
Next day when opening AS it tells me that my project is in detached Head state. Commits dont work anymore. Checking out the master or any other branch is not working too. I receive the error message "Couldn't checkout mater. Revision not found."

Pull request, push request or anything else related to the repository is not working anymore. Due to that version control is not possible anymore.

I honestly don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

In that instance:

- close Android Studio
- switch back to command
- do a git status to check you are indeed in a detached HEAD state
- do a `git checkout master`
- open AS again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case just open & close AS worked.
I'm using `Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 1`.